# Buscar o certificado no cliente, e não no servidor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estou precisando buscar o certificado, e gostaria que buscasse no cliente, e não no servidor, eu tento fazer desta forma:

```
 public static X509Certificate2 EscolherCertificado(string serial)
    {
        var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        var Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serial, false);
        if (fcollection.Count == 1)
        {
            return fcollection[0];
        }
        else { cod = "00000"; msgm = "Certificado não identificado, reinicie o certificado e tente novamente"; return null; }

    }
```

Porém quando publico no servidor não dá certo. Possui alguma maneira q eu consigo fazer isso ?

Como posso fazer, porque neste caso está retornando erro

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Pois nem aparece para o usuário digitar a senha do certificado, preciso mudar algo na assinatura do arquivo também ? Obrigado.

**EDIT**
Até agora não obtive sucesso, eu preciso que a aplicação consiga pegar o certificado instalado no cliente. E apareça a senha para digitar no cliente.

**EDIT**
Tentei mudar para `var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);` porém também não busca o certificado no cliente.

**EDIT**
Encontrei este [link](https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/25/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-5-working-with-client-certificates-in-a-web-project/) na internet, porém não consegui funcionar, ele informa como pegar o usuário do cliente. O que posso estar fazendo de errado. Alterei o código para:

```
public static X509Certificate2 EscolherCertificado(string serial)
        {
        X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection findResult = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serial, true);
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
            if (findResult.Count == 1)
            {
                clientCertificate = findResult[0];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to locate the correct client certificate.");
            }
            cod = "0000"; msgm = clientCertificate.ToString(); return clientCertificate;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            userCaStore.Close();
        }
```

**EDIT**
Existe alguma forma de pegar via javascript então, eu preciso de pegar o certificado que está no cliente para assinar, enquanto a aplicação roda no servidor. Preciso pegar o certificado de acordo com o serial que está cadastrado no banco, e assinar o arquivo `xml`.

Lembrando que já tentei trocar para `LocalMachine`, porém também não resolveu.

```
  X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

Comment: Se você quer buscar no cliente então utilize alguma aplicação/módulo que seja executado no cliente (client side) e não no servidor (server side).

Comment: Eu preciso tudo no servidor, e só buscar no cliente.

Comment: Mari, você ai de novo hahaha...

Comment: Que certificado em exato você está querendo?

Comment: @gabrielfalieri eu de novo, como smp hahahahahaha, estou tentando pelo A3, smartcard

Comment: Vale lembrar que o certificado A3 ele tem uma proteção extra, dessa forma a chave privada fica inacessível, exceto pelo hardware... o que você consegue pegar é a publica

Comment: Qual seria a solução, será que tem alguma ? rs, o certificado vai ficar no cliente, a aplicação precisa selecionar o certificado, e assinar um arquivo que estará na máquina do cliente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88099/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-marianac-costa).

Comment: A solução será a construção de um serviço WCF onde vai ser criado um método que vai executar a operação que precisa ser realizada, e dentro deste método você vai utilizar seu código para buscar o certificado. E este serviço será instalado na máquina cliente assim poderá pegar o certificado.